# Is it possible to restore a tensorflow estimator from saved model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I use `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()` to train my custom estimator. My dataset is partitioned 8:1:1 for training, evaluation and test. At the end of the training, I would like to restore the best model, and evaluate the model using `tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate()` with the test data. The best model is currently exported using `tf.estimator.BestExporter`.

While `tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate()` accepts `checkpoint_path` and restores variables, I cannot find any easy way to use the exported model generated by `tf.estimator.BestExporter`. I could of course keep all checkpoints during training, and look for the best model by myself, but that seems quite suboptimal.

Could anyone tell me an easy workaround? Maybe it is possible to convert a saved model to a checkpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope someone else will find a cleaner way..

`tf.estimator.BestExporter` exports the best model like this:

```
<your_estimator.model_dir>
+--export
   +--best_exporter
      +--xxxxxxxxxx(timestamp)
         +--saved_model.pb
         +--variables
            +--variables.data-00000-of-00001
            +--variables.index
```

On the other hand, in `your_estimator.model_dir`, checkpoints are stored in three files.

```
model.ckpt-xxxx.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-xxxx.index
model.ckpt-xxxx.meta
```

First, I used `tf.estimator.Estimator.evaluate(..., checkpoint_path='<your_estimator.model_dir>/export/best_exporter/<xxxxxxxxxx>/variables/variables')`, but this did not work.

After copying one of the metafiles in `your_estimator.model_dir`, and renaming it "variables.meta", the evaluation seemed to work all right.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/WarmStartSettings

It can load weights in pb file and continue training, which worked on my project.

You can set warm-start as follows:

```
ws = WarmStartSettings(ckpt_to_initialize_from="/[model_dir]/export/best-exporter/[timestamp]/variables/variables")
```

And then everythring will be Ok

Comment: Works in tf 1.15! Feed `ws` from the answer into `model = tf.estimator.Estimator( ... , warm_start_from=ws)` and calling both `model.evaluate` and `tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model, ... )` work AS LONG AS there are no checkpoints in the model dir. So make sure model_dir is empty, and then you can either eval or continue training this way.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the resolution to @SumNeuron's Github issue `tf.contrib.estimator.SavedModelEstimator` is the way to load from a saved model to an `Estimator`.

The following works for me:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.SavedModelEstimator(saved_model_dir)
prediction_results = estimator.predict(input_fn)
```

Baffling that this is essentially completely undocumented.

Comment: +1 but for this to work you need to have saved all modes (train, eval, predict). For e.g. when saving with `tf.estimator.BestExporter` only the predict mode seems to be saved

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) API but I think I know what you are looking for, although it is equally annoying.

From this [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1GKAqEo7qSr6kMAgxPrOrudA5eLndQ6Ub), which is a toy custom [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) with some bells and whistles added on:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(<model_dir>)
predict_fn(pred_features) # pred_features corresponds to your input features
```

and this estimator both uses a `BestExporter`

```
exporter = tf.estimator.BestExporter(
    name="best_exporter",
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn,
    exports_to_keep=5
) # this will keep the 5 best checkpoints
```

as well as just exports the model after training:

`est.export_savedmodel('./here', serving_input_receiver_fn)`

If it irks you that the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) API has no "proper" way to load a `SavedModel`, I already created an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23824) on GitHub.

However, if you are trying to load it onto a different device, see my other questions:

- [TensorFlow v1.10+ load SavedModel with different device placement or manually set dynamic device placement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53356558/tensorflow-v1-10-load-savedmodel-with-different-device-placement-or-manually-se)
- [TensorFlow Estimator clear_deivces in exporters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409652/tensorflow-estimator-clear-deivces-in-exporters)

which address device placement, for which there are other GitHub issues

- [No clear_devices in BestExporter #23900](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23900)
- [Relative Device Placement #23834](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23900)

In short, at the moment, the device you train on is the device you **MUST** have available when you load your [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) if you export using the [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) exporters. If you manually export your [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) in the `model_fn` if you set `clear_devices`, then you should be good to go. At the moment there does not seem to be a way to change this after you export your model.